# How to delete every post of a specific user from VBulletin?

Tags: vbulletin

Is possible in VBulletin to make invisible / delete every single post by an user? Is it possible from the interface or through a query on the db?

Comment: @JohnConde: but I want to delete only the posts from 1 user, not all the posts in the db.. and how to distinguish between threads and posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread in the vBulletin support forums](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-suggestions/402236-remove-user-posts-when-deleting-a-user-account)

> When your in the Admin CP (Control Panel) on a user. The same drop down to Delete that user is a option to delete all posts, visitor messages, and private messages.

Here is the [documentation for the Admin Control Panel](https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/vb5_admincp).